# ASPXAUTH Session invalidate on logout with OAUTH

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, session, oauth

I have a MVC-4 application that use Facebook Oauth for login. We implement Oath base on default **OAuthWebSecurity** provide by MVC4. Then I encounter **.ASPXAUTH** cookies security issue: The scenario is as follow:

1. Login as User 1
2. Copy .ASPXAUTH cookie from User 1 and remember it
3. Log out User 1
4. Login as User 2
5. Replace .ASPXAUTH cookies with value from User 1
6. Refresh page

Tadah, that when User 1 appear from login window not User 2 any more. My question is: How does it happend. Is there any way to fully log User 1 out?

P/S: In log out function we have call

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
Session.Clear();
Session.Abandon();
//and clear all cookies
```

Also facebook javascript `FB.logout` has been call from client side

Comment: Please read my question carefully. It's not a problem when user login facebook again. Its just .ASPXAUTH cookie replacement

Comment: Did you resolve this? I am also facing same issue without solution

Comment: I only did a trick that store both session ID and aspxauth into session variable and check it. If aspxauth mismatch with session id then it is changed by user. In that case invalidate user

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. could u show how u did, i mean can u post the code?

Comment: What do you mean by `Replace .ASPXAUTH cookies with value from User 1`? Didn't you say above (step 3) that User 1 has been logged out? If so, there's no such thing as "cookie replacement" because that cookie doesn't exist...I mean if you've properly destroyed it when logging out

Comment: That's the problem, even when user 1 logout, those cookies still not invalidate so somehow if someone get .ASPXAUTH cookies, they got control forever...

Comment: @TrinhHoangNhu, how did u do that and where? can u show me code snippet?

Comment: Please wait, I must ask for permission...