# OAuthWebSecurity Formsauthentication is not clearing sessions mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, session, google-oauth

Ours is a MVC4 application.
We are OAuth & Formsauthentication to allow login with google, facebook & twitter.

For the first time when I login using google..
I am redirected to google page and I have provided credentials it logs me in, thats all fine.

After logout, and re-login, I am able to login automatically.
I think the cookies in the browser are not cleared though I have cleared them in logoff.

```
    public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
        //Clears out Session
        Response.Cookies.Clear();

        //Signs out of WebSecurity and FormsAuthentication
        WebSecurity.Logout();
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

        // clear authentication cookie
        HttpCookie cookie1 = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, "");
        cookie1.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie1);

        Session.Clear();
        Session.Abandon();

        return RedirectToAction(AXN_DFLT, CNTLR_DFLT);
    }
```

After logoff I should be redirected to google page again on re-login.
but it is not happening.
somebody pls advise?

same kind of question here : [ASPXAUTH Session invalidate on logout with OAUTH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20537851/aspxauth-session-invalidate-on-logout-with-oauth)

but no answer!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first sight, there doesn't seem to be any problem in your described question. Your solution seems to be working fine. It seems to me that you are not understanding how OAuth, FormsAuthenticate, Sessions and Cookies fit altogether. For the sake of simplicity, I'll outline the process flow you have described and explain each of them...

The scenario is that you are NOT logged into neither your website nor your google account.

1. You browse to your website login page
2. Click on the "Login with Google" button: This redirects you to the Google Account login dialog, so you're not on your website anymore...you're now knocking on Google's door
3. You login successfully with Google: Google will issue a cookie (for Google's services only)

Up to this point, your browser owns one cookie...Google's one

4.You are redirected back to your website: Your website noticed an access token(not cookie) issued by Google and then your website will issue its own cookie which has nothing to do with Google's one

Up to this point, your logged in with Google and your website, meaning your browser owns 2 valid cookies (Google's and your website's)

5.Later on, you log out of your website: This action destroys any session related to YOUR website (including the cookie for your website). Notice that, Google's cookie is still valid, in fact, if you go to your gmail, youtube or any other Google's service you will perfectly bypass authentication because you haven't logged out from Google...ONLY from your website.

6.Then you decide to log back into your website by click the "Login with Google" button: This action will take you to Google's but, because Google detects that you are already authenticated (logged in) it doesn't need to re-authenticate you, it already knows who you are and does not prompt the login dialog, instead, it redirects you back to your website issuing a fresh new access token.

Basically, you are not required to login with Google again if you are already logged in

Hope it makes sense

Comment: Thanks!!I understand this.But what if I want to login with another account google, should I always have to manually clear the browser history and which seems not correct way?LogOff should clear all the sessions is'nt it?

Comment: If you want to login with another Google account, then, ask yourself what would you do if you go to GMail and you want to login with another account? You have to log out first, right? That's exactly the same thing you are doing here. I still don't think you understand how cookies work. You will have to log out of Google because you are logged in with Google.

Comment: Okay, my users who logs in to the site using google or twitter, if they want to complete logout, should they go to google and logout always?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what said in my answer. Are you implying your users are going to share the same computer and the same browser session????